# Can not exactly insert all rows to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014

i am trying to insert 483 records from .csv file by "GenericParsing" to my table in sqlserver using stored stored procedure but i see 473 records in my table.
this is my code.
i dont have any trigger in my table.
please help me!

```
using (GenericParser parser = new GenericParser())
{
    parser.SetDataSource(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    parser.ColumnDelimiter = Convert.ToChar(",");
    parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
    parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 10;
    parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
    parser.MaxRows = 500;
    parser.TextQualifier = '\"';
    while (parser.Read())
    {
        string stringField1 = parser["stringField1"] != null ? parser["stringField1"].ToString() : "0";
        string stringField2 = parser["stringField2"] != null ? parser["stringField2"].ToString() : "0";
        string stringField3 = parser["stringField3"] != null ? parser["stringField3"].ToString() : "0";
        string doubleField1 = parser["doubleField1"] != null ? parser["doubleField1"].ToString() : "0";
        string doubleField2 = parser["doubleField2"] != null ? parser["doubleField2"].ToString() : "0";
        string doubleField3 = parser["doubleField3"] != null ? parser["doubleField3"].ToString() : "0";
        string doubleField4 = parser["doubleField4"] != null ? parser["doubleField4"].ToString() : "0";
        string modifiedDate = parser["modifiedDate"] != null ? parser["modifiedDate"].ToString() : "0";


        //my connection string in con.
        string con = "";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("con");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        cmd.CommandText = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stringField1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stringField1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stringField2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stringField2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stringField3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = stringField3;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@doubleField1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = doubleField1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@doubleField2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = doubleField2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@doubleField3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = doubleField3;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@doubleField4", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = doubleField4;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@modifiedDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = modifiedDate;

        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string w = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
                  if (w == "1")
        {
                        continue;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error in inserting");
        }
    }
}
```

i take stored procedure name from combo box

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Are you saying that when you executed this code to insert 480 items from a CSV file, that as a result 980 rows were created in the database? Can you explain what the code is meant to be doing and what exactly you are doing to get the result?

Comment: look at the Sql code and make sure you are not Truncating the data prior to insert or make sure there are no triggers on that table.. can you show us what the Insert query looks like..?

Comment: I would change this line `parser["stringField1"] != null ?` for all of your ternary checks to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(parser["stringField1"]) ? parser["stringField1"].ToString() : 0.ToString();`

Comment: If your files are properly formatted, you could probably use SqlBulkInsert and have SQL Server do the heavy lifting for you, instead of inserting the rows one by one. If you insist on inserting the rows one by one, the least you can do is setting the SqlConnection and SqlCommand outside the loop, and inside just setting parameters values and execute.

Comment: hi Zohar and thanks for commenting. when i do what you said this error appear "Procedure or function "EInsert" has too many arguments specified."

Comment: It seems to me that you have configured the parser to skip 10 rows using ```parser.SkipStartingDataRows = 10;```

Comment: oh...no.....a Ridiculous mistake! thanks,Peter.